# WSO2 EMM iOS enrollment error: "The Registration Authority's response is invalid"

Tags: ios, ssl, certificate, wso2, mdm

Setup WSO2 EMM server on a Mac (10.8). Created self-signed certificates according to the iOS server configuration guide:
https://docs.wso2.org/display/EMM100/iOS+Server+Configurations

Was able to successfully download and install the self-signed Root CA on iPad (iOS 7).
However, getting error on iPad during WSO2 Profile Service installation:

"Profile Installation Failed: The Registration Authority's response is invalid."

Tried with both server domain name as well as IP address as the CN for certificates got the same error.

There is no error log on the MDM server side.

Here is the iOS error log:

```
Mar 18 11:55:09 XXXXX-iPad profiled[2191] <Notice>: (Error) MC: Cannot retrieve SCEP identity: NSError:
Desc   : The Registration Authority’s response is invalid.
US Desc: The Registration Authority’s response is invalid.
Domain : MCSCEPErrorDomain
Code   : 22003
Type   : MCFatalError
Mar 18 11:55:09 XXXXX-iPad profiled[2191] <Notice>: (Error) MC: Failure occurred while retrieving profile during OTA Profile Enrollment: NSError:
Desc   : The Registration Authority’s response is invalid.
US Desc: The Registration Authority’s response is invalid.
Domain : MCSCEPErrorDomain
Code   : 22003
Type   : MCFatalError
Mar 18 11:55:09 XXXXX-iPad profiled[2191] <Notice>: (Error) MC: Installation failed. Error: NSError:
Desc   : Profile Installation Failed
Sugg   : The Registration Authority’s response is invalid.
US Desc: Profile Installation Failed
US Sugg: The Registration Authority’s response is invalid.
Domain : MCInstallationErrorDomain
Code   : 4001
Type   : MCFatalError
...Underlying error:
NSError:
Desc   : The Registration Authority’s response is invalid.
US Desc: The Registration Authority’s response is invalid.
Domain : MCSCEPErrorDomain
Code   : 22003
Type   : MCFatalError
Extra info:
{
   isPrimary = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be many issues which cause this actions. First as in docs you have to sign your generated RA using your generated CA. Open the certificate and see whether the signer is the root CA which you have created. Next thing is when importing to the wso2mobilemdm.jks you have to specify an alias and a private key password. EMM ships with some default configurations. If it mismatches from your alias and the password this will not work. To check this just navigate to the {installation folder}/repository/conf/mdm-config.xml file. Check whether you have the proper RA configurations there. Once you change these entries you need to restart the server. Let me know whether this works for you.